# Recursively select file in mac - need to prettier all files in directory

Tags: linux, macos, prettier

I am following [this medium post](https://medium.com/@ajaysaini.official/how-to-run-prettier-on-all-js-files-in-a-directory-7d2d96e66919).

Running the command `prettier --write ./src/**/*.{js,jsx,scss}` works perfectly fine on windows machine.

However, when using Mac machine, this command doesn't go recursively on files that present on sub-folders.

What is the difference between windows and mac on this?

Comment: Answered in this github discussion:
[https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2078](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2078)

Answer (score 1):

You could use find with -exec, like so

```
find src -iname \*.js -or -iname \*.jsx -exec prettier --write {} \;
```

The arguments:

- src: the directory (be careful to not run on .git, node_modules, etc
- -iname: case insensitive name
- -or: or, to chain options together, in this case iname
- -exec: execute the following command for every item found. It replaces {} with the item found. Exec needs \; at the end to know when your command is over.

Before you execute it, you could prepend echo to preview what commands will be running, like so

```
find src -iname \*.js -or -iname \*.jsx -exec echo prettier --write {} \;
```